# Adding icon to zend form validator

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-validate

I am working on a zend form, but I want to add a tick and a cross depending on the input from the user in front of my zend form validator message, how can I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Validators by default dont have 'it's good' message, so how you plan to show it? Maybe you can use CSS `:before` to add icons?

Comment: You can edit/change your validator messages by adding set description to your element